# Eclipse Debugger - Avoid "Source Not Found" pages when stepping into code

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging a Spring Web application in Eclipse. Whenever I step into service methods I get the page **"Class File Editor: Source not found"** after pressing **F5 (Step Into)**.

Example:
[image]

Expected action: I stay within the code of my application. When pressing F5 I get directed to the next line in my application code only. I don't have any breakpoints in the libraries, I only have 1 breakpoint in my application.

In other words I should never get directed outside my code if I didn't put a breakpoint there. I can't press F6 (Step Over) because that would step over my custom code that I do want to see.

Comment: What is about _[Run To Line](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/menus/run/ref-run_to_line.htm)_ instead of _Step Into_ or _Step Over_?

Comment: I shouldn't have to do "Run To Line" because that would require me to keep placing my cursor at the next lines I want to execute. The whole point is to seamlessly keep pressing a key (like F5 or F6) to step through, but in the app code only.

Answer (score 1):

**[Use Step Filters](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-usestepfilters.htm):**

> Select the ***Use Step Filters*** command to change whether step filters should be used in the Debug View. You can also use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.
>
> Step filters are commonly used to filter out types that you do not wish to see or step through while debugging.
>
> For example, if you did not want to the see or step through anything from the class *java.lang.Object*, you would add this to the list of filtered types. Adding types to the list of those to be filtered can be done in one of two ways:
>
> - Via the context menu - **Right click on the stack frame for the type you wish to filter** and use the *[Filter Type](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-filtertype.htm)* or *[Filter Package](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-filterpackage.htm)* command.
> - Via the  Opens the Step Filtering **preference page *Java > Debug > Step Filtering*** preference page.